# Sum Filtered Values Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am finding the sum of filtered values while ignoring #DIV/0! errors. As such, I combined the following formulas:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,$I$2:$I$349)
```

and

```
=SUMIF($I$2:$I$349,"<>#DIV/0!")
```

To get:

```
SUBTOTAL(9,SUMIF($I$2:$I$349,"<>#DIV/0!"))
```

However, excel returns an error. Any insights?
Is it that I cannot place a formula within another formula?

Comment: subtotal need a range, you provide a sum it appears. BTW, error description would be good.

Comment: You can't use `SUMIF` like that within `SUBTOTAL` because `SUBTOTAL` expects a reference to a range of values to operate over. `SUMIF` is returning a value, not a reference.

Comment: @ZAT, just a standard error saying there is a problem with the formula. No specifics. How else could I combine these formulas?

Comment: @grovesNL OK. How else could I combine these formulas?

Comment: exactly what are you trying to get? sum of filtered values. What are these values? what are I col and G col contain?

Comment: @Navron: We need to know more about your sheet in order to give you advice about a better way to accomplish this. For example, is `SUBTOTAL` even necessary?

Comment: @ZAT Ok, the worksheet I am working on contains filtered values. as such, I use '=SUBTOTAL(9,$I$2:$I$349)' to find the sum of a range of percentage values. However, I need the formula to ignore DIV/0s, so I want to also use '=SUMIF($I$2:$I$349,"<>#DIV/0!")'. So I am simply finding the filtered sum, but ignoring DIV/0s

Comment: @Navron FWIW, I found your question well stated, and you walked through your attempts showing what you had tried. For those asking for the error, the formula throws a `#VALUE!` error, due to SUBTOTAL looking for a range. I've tested the answer I posted on some sample data and it appears to do the trick. Try it out, and if it works, feel free to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Excel are you using?

In `Excel 2010` and later versions `AGGREGATE` function works a little bit like `SUBTOTAL` - it can perform various functions while ignoring hidden rows.......but it also has options to ignore error values, so without any helper columns you can use this single formula

`=AGGREGATE(9,7,I2:I349)`

`9` denotes `"sum"` as per `SUBTOTAL` while `7` as the 2nd argument indicates that error values and hidden values should be ignored. There are other options, see Excel Help for more

Comment: Brilliant! I learn something about Excel everyday! This should be the answer. Simple, easy to understand, and easy to edit if something should happen or change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found this bit of brilliance with some digging on the webs: http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?p=760730

It's a difficult formula to follow, but should do the trick.

```
{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER($I$2:$I$349),$I$2:$I$349)*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($I$2:$I$349,ROW($I$2:$I$349)-MIN(ROW($I$2:$I$349)),0,1))))}
```

It's an array formula, so make sure to press Ctrl + Shift + Enter (instead of just Enter).

I can't pretend to understand it all without really digging into it, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use a *helper column*

In **H2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(G2,"")
```

and copy down  and then use:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,$H$2:$H$349)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(9,$I$2:$I$349),"")
```